# How to diagnose cause of wildfly 10.1 going down

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jpa, wildfly

I am using CentOs and wildlfy 10.1.0 in my system, I have started wildfly as run forever, but wildfly stops working sometimes. Can you please help me to diagnose the cause how it went down, as logs do not mention anything. nothing of wildfly getting stopped.

I deploy the following things on server:

1. One Ejb module
2. Four war modules

there are 5 schedulars running in the system 
and I am connecting to 2 database one through JPA and other through JDBC

the last log scrapped was our schedular message and then the wildfly stopped automatically without any error messages

```
2017-08-03 04:01:59,023 DEBUG
[com.ecomm.pl4sms.loader.receiver.SendHighPrioMsgToSqlBox]
(DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) Scanning sender fake true
```

I am using CentOS 7 and Wildfly 10.1.0-Final, Postgres 9.6, Jdk 1.8, Mysql 5-7

Please help me to diagnose the cause why it could have stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Keep tabs on the memory usage of the wildfly proces. If the Java setting for max heap space isn't reached but the Linux kernel determines wildfly is the most memory hungry process and it's running close to max memory usage (say Java max heap is set to 16Gb on a system with 16Gb memory), it will kill the proces without any trace in a logfile. The Java process won't perform an out-of-memory heapdump as it believes it has room left to expand.